# Youtube Api multiple videos using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have been trying to display multiple videos using the YouTube Api with the video Id's coming from an ajax call. However the best i can get to is it only loading one video, rather than all of them.

I have seen a few similar questions on here and it is because the API ready function can only run once. I have tried things like moving the API Ready function though to outside the loop, outside the ajax function, creating an array for the id's etc... but anything else i have tried, i end up with nothing displaying.

The code within the ajax call for displaying one is -

```
success: function(data) {
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

$.each(data, function(i, itemList) {
    var strList = "";
    for (i = 0; i < itemList.length; i += 1) {
        item = itemList[i];
        video = item[4];
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
            new YT.Player(i, {
                height: '250',
                width: '500',
                playerVars: {
                    'rel': 0,
                    'showinfo': 0,
                    'frameborder': 0,
                    'modestbranding': 1
                },
                videoId: video,
                events: {}
            });
        }
        strList += "<div id=" + i + "></div><br/>";
    }
    $("#random_list").html(strList);
});
}
```

The three divs are being created fine but only the last one is being changed to the iframe and displaying the video. Can anyone see where I am going wrong or point me in the right direction on how to fix it??

Comment: try to append each element with data instead of concatenate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by changing the ajax success to -

```
    success:function(data){
        var playerInfoList = [];
        $.each(data, function(i, itemList) {
            for (i = 0; i < itemList.length; i += 1) {
                item = itemList[i];
                playerNo = i + 1;
                playerInfoList.push({
                    id: 'player' + playerNo, 
                    videoId: item[4]
                });
            }   
        });
        loadVideos();
    }
```

which pushes the video details into an array and then calls the loadVideo function to then create the divs and players using the array -

```
function loadVideos() {
 var tag = document.createElement('script');
 tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
 var strList = '';

 window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {   

      if (typeof playerInfoList === 'undefined') return;
      for (var i = 0; i < playerInfoList.length; i++) {
       vidNo = i + 1;
       strList += "<div id='player" + vidNo + "'></div><br/>";
      }

      $("#video_list").html(strList);

      for (var i = 0; i < playerInfoList.length; i++) {
       var curplayer = createPlayer(playerInfoList[i]);
       players[i] = curplayer;
      }  
 }

 var players = new Array();

 function createPlayer(playerInfo) {
  return new YT.Player(playerInfo.id, {
   videoId: playerInfo.videoId,
  });
 }
}
```